# Создание своей сессии в ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Дано: ubuntu 11.10. Как создать свою сессию по аналогии как это делает cairo-dock? Т.е. на экране, где выбирается логин, можно выбрать оболочки для загрузки (прим. gnome, gnome (no effects), ubuntu, ubuntu-2d etc). Собственно тут и нужно впихнуть свою. Мало того, неплохо бы понять, где смотреть существующие варианты загрузки, чтобы по аналогии можно было создать свою.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите в `/usr/share/xsessions`, там должны быть `.desktop`-файлы с сессиями. Еще можно посмотреть в `/etc/X11/sessions`.

Спецификация FD.o на desktop entry files, вроде бы, вот: http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, правда ответ таки нагуглил раньше - проблема была в том, что толком не знал как это называется :) Надо добавить, что вообще неплохо еще порыться в папке /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions - тут, как оказалось, хранятся файлики для создания самих сессий, а в xsessions - уже "варианты" загрузки системы.

P.S. А вот за ссылку отдельное спасибо.
P.S.S. Вопрос возник для того, что бы убрать unity и заменить его AWN (avant-window-navigator). К слову, cairo-dock при установке создает свои файлы в обоих папках - по аналогии можно разобраться как создать свою сессию.